# How to pass data to screen from drawer customcomponent in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a drawer navigation that contains some inputs for filter some data, and I want to pass values from contentComponent to search screen to retrive data from server

drawer

```
export default createDrawerNavigator({
  Search:{ screen: Search,
         },
  },{
    contentComponent: (props, navigation) => (<FilterDrawer {...props} />),
    drawerPosition: 'right',
});
```

search.js

```
export default class Search extends Component<{}> {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
 }

render(){
 return(
<View></View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't use any library. I am new to react native and just created an app that list some data from sql. Problem is on my custom drawer content. How can I get parameters when user open drawer and select some filter area?

Comment: you can use React Context API to pass data between components. Here is for your reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Did you use any libraries to management your state like redux, mobx ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the data through navigation state as:

```
  this.props.navigation.navigate('SearchPage',
     {                         
       userID: '123456',
       email: 'abc@gmail.com',                 
  });
```

To access props in `SearchPage`

```
 const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
 const {userID, email} = params;
```

But its better to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: can you write an example of use context in react native